# Wildcard subdomain in .htaccess from file.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, wildcard-subdomain

We are trying to redirect user.php pages in our site to subdomains.

Our goal is to point `http://user943934.domain.com` to `http://domain.com/user/user943934.php`

Our htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /user/%1.php [QSA]
```

We tried this htaccess to redirect directories in the same manner so I'm not sure why it woill not work with page.php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [QSA]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: first of all i think you are looking at it wrong. you should try to point it to something like users.php?u=user943934

Comment: You'll need a wildcard subdomain entry either in your DNS and/or apache virtual hosts.

Comment: I got the wildcard subdomain setup already in .htaccess